# Android NDK update vulkan.hpp

Tags: android, android-ndk, vulkan

I'm currently porting vulkan code to android, which uses a recent version of vulkan.hpp. The codes uses designated initializers (C++20), which only works with *vulkan.hpp* if *VULKAN_HPP_NO_STRUCT_CONSTRUCTORS* is defined. However, the vulkan.hpp shipped with the current android ndk r22 does not support the define and therefore designated initializers.

Does anyone know if there is an easy way to upgrade the vulkan headers for android?

Could it work if I just replace the vulkan headers and update the dynamic loader to support the newly introduced functions? I am aware that I will not be able to use the new functions because they will be missing in the shared library provided by the OS during runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a header without any library. You can simply get the latest from [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Headers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Headers/tree/master/include/vulkan) and use them instead.